# How to ask User for function input on Main Function with python?

Tags: python, function, program-entry-point

I need to ask the user for input on entering height and width to find perimeter and area while using the main function, I'm getting a simple error which is (    Area= (Width * Height)
NameError: name 'Width' is not defined)  but I've tried everything I know to fix it

```
print("Find the Area and Perimeter of a retangle.")
def main():
    Width = input("Enter the Width:")
    Height = input("Enter the Height:")
    Area()
    Perimeter()
def Area():
    Area= (Width * Height)
    print("The area is", Area)
def Perimeter():
    Perimeter = (Width * 2 + Height * 2)
main()
```

Comment: Width and Height of main() function cannot be accessed in Area().

Comment: Pass values as parameters, using global variables usually is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the Code:

```
    print("Find the Area and Perimeter of a retangle.")
def main():
    Width = input("Enter the Width:")
    Height = input("Enter the Height:")
    Area(Width, Height)
    Perimeter(Width, Height)
def Area(Width, Height):
    Area= (Width * Height)
    print("The area is", Area)
def Perimeter(Width, Height):
    Perimeter = (Width * 2 + Height * 2)
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have pointed out already, the functions `Area` and `Perimeter` don't know what is happening inside `main`. This is the perfect opportunity  to learn about classes. I would restructure this into a class as follows:

```
class main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Width = int(input("Enter the Width:"))
        self.Height = int(input("Enter the Height:"))

    def area(self):
        a = (self.Width * self.Height)
        print("The area is", a)

    def perimeter(self):
        p = self.Width * 2 + self.Height * 2
        print("The perimeter is", p)

# instantiate a "main" object called "rectangle" 
rectangle = main()

# call the "area" method
rectangle.area()

# call the "perimeter" method
rectangle.perimeter()
```

Comment: There's little need for a class here. Function parameters and return values are all that is needed.

Comment: Granted, this is definitely overkill, but this seemed like a teachable moment. Especially since `area` and `perimeter` are linked to the shape itself.

Comment: Your class doesn't abstract a shape; it abstracts a *program*, and there's no need for such a class in Python. (Unlike, say, Java, top-level functions are both permissible and idiomatic.)

Answer (score 0):

Your functions should take arguments and return values where possible.

```
def main():
    print("Find the Area and Perimeter of a retangle.")
    width = input("Enter the Width:")
    height = input("Enter the Height:")
    print("The area is", area(width, height))
    print("The perimeter is", perimeter(width, height))


def area(w, h):
    return w * h


def perimeter(w, h):
    return w*2 + h*2


main()
```

`area` and `perimeter` should not be responsible for doing any output: they take the necessary inputs as arguments and return the value.

Your `main` function is responsible for all I/O: it prompts the user for a width and a height, and uses `area` and `perimeter` to get the values to output.

If you want to further break down what `main` does, you could define additional input and output routines:

```
def get_input():
    width = input("Enter the width: ")
    height = input("Enter the height: ")
    return width, height


def give_output(a, p):
    print("The area is", a)
    print("The perimeter is", p)


def main():
    width, height = get_input()
    give_output(area(width, height), perimeter(width, height))
```